# How do I loop through an array of buttons and only continue looping if the user clicks the next button in the array

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Not sure if this is exactly the correct approach for this but I have an array of buttons that spawn on the screen and after a few seconds it changes location and I have to click the buttons in the order they appeared initially.

Following is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/5b64xcsr/2/):

```js
let arrayButtons = [];
let goButton = document.getElementById("inputButton");

function Buttons(color, height, width, top, left, order) {
  this.order = order;
  this.btn = document.createElement("button");
  this.btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
  this.btn.style.height = height;
  this.btn.style.width = width;
  this.btn.style.position = "absolute";
  document.body.appendChild(this.btn);
  this.setLocation = function(top, left) {
    this.btn.style.top = top;
    this.btn.style.left = left;
  };
  this.setLocation(top, left);
}

function createButtons(numOfButtons) {
  console.log(numOfButtons);
  let color;
  let heightVal;
  let widthVal;
  let top;
  let left;
  let currentButton;
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++) {
    color = "#" + genRandomColor();
    heightVal = "60px";
    widthVal = "120px";
    let x = window.innerWidth - 100;
    let y = window.innerHeight - 100;
    top = 90 + "px";
    left = i * 120 + "px";
    currentButton = new Buttons(color, heightVal, widthVal, top, left, i);
    arrayButtons.push(currentButton);
  }

}

function genRandomColor() {
  let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  return randomColor;
}

function change() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let x = window.innerWidth - 100;
    let y = window.innerHeight - 200;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayButtons.length; i++) {
      randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * x + 50);
      randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * y + 50);
      arrayButtons[i].setLocation(
        randomX + 'px',
        randomY + 'px');
    }
  }, 5000);
}

function isValid(range) {
  range = document.getElementById("textField").value;
  if (range < 2 || range > 10) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

// idea.. if the user clicks on the button in the order of the array it works
// for the hint, just make the value equal to the index number + 1 

function clickHandler() {
  let minMax = isValid();
  if (minMax == true) {
    createButtons(document.getElementById("textField").value);
    change();
  } else {
    window.alert("Must be between 2 and 10");
  }

}

goButton.onclick = clickHandler;
```

```html
<p>How Many Buttons To Create?</p>
<input id="textField" type="text">
<button type="button" id="inputButton">Go!</button>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Your problem has 2 parts. Animation and validation. Assuming its valid, animation will run and move buttons. On click, you update validation to either true or false. In animation, you check if validation is true, continue, else stop

Comment: I don't want the buttons to move. I already have it so the buttons move after a few seconds but they have to click the buttons in the order they appeared normally and if they make a mistake, i want it to break out of the loop and alert the user that they are wrong

Comment: If you could share your code, it would be easier for us to help

Comment: sorry, the code was too long so i just put it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gvu92sze/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button class="buttonClass">1</button>
```

JS

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".buttonClass");
let currentBtn = 0;
btns.forEach(function(btn, crtIndex){
    btn.onclick = function(){
        if(currentBtn === crtIndex){
            currentBtn++;
            console.log("correct");
        }
    };
});
```